# How to show collectionView cell one at a time with vertical scrolling

Tags: swift, layout, uicollectionviewcell

I want to show one cell at a time in collection View while sliding vertically. But it's showing half of next view. how to set it for one cell at a time?

```
class CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var lable: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    let reuseIdentifier = "collectionViewCellId"
    var lableArray = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.lableArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        let item = lableArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()
        cell.lable.text = item
        return cell
    }

}
```

[image: t]

Comment: Can you pls include some code?

Comment: Change `return self.lableArray.count` to `return 1` inside `numberOfItemsInSection`.

Comment: @Kamran i want to show all the cell but one at a time not only one cell.

Comment: @RanuDhurandhar then you need to set the height of your cell same as collectionView as proposed in below answers. If you need to create view as above then you might need to implement your custom view.

Answer (score 3):

You need to conform `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and then use

```
internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` has the delegate method `sizeForItemAt` which can be used to give `CGSize` for the `UICollectionViewCell` you are displaying. You just need to conform and you are good to go!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
     //....

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return collectionView.size //In case if your collection is of full size
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating the UICollectionView, Add `FlowLayout`

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionView.ScrollDirection.vertical
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: collectView_WIDTH, height: collectView_HEIGHT)
    let collectionViewItem = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init())
    collectionViewItem.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
```

Add

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: collectView_WIDTH, height: collectView_HEIGHT)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things:

1. First of all:

> Setup UICollectionView **delegate, dataSource** and set ***isPagingEnabled = true***

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true

   // rest of your work
    
}
```

2. Secondly:

> You have to conform **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout** and return the same width and height or your collectionView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(
        width: self.collectionView.frame.width,
        height: self.collectionView.frame.height
    )
}
```

Cheers..