# How to Center Individual Cells to Screen in UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have two items in my horizontal collection view, and I am trying to make center them, so that with each swipe, a cell is completely center and evenly spaced from the margins. Also only a single cell can be on the screen at once.

Here is what it looks like at the moment. The cells are not event spaced from the sides.

[image]

```
extension HomeVC : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width - 25, height: 100)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        
        return .init(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }
}
```

They should be like this, equally spaced from the margins.

[image]

Comment: my min spacing for cells on the story board is 0.

Comment: Here is a fix, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77443552/7385095

Answer (score 0):

Make minimum spacing for lines and cell == 0

[Please refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDpG7.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width - 20, height: 100)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    return .init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10
}
```

Also check Paging Enabled. Fits your case.